# maven repository not found, how to change them all?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to compile many poms, unfortunately many of them point to a domain that doesnt exist `domain:8081/repo` and I want them to be domain.com:8081 ...

So, I configured the `~/.m2/settings.xml` with the mirror and the proper url, as far as I remember, if the pom url is not reached, it will look for this other url and if not go to `repo1.maven.org`, is this correct?

Still, when compiling keep saying the repo was not found... any idea?

Thanks,

EDIT----

Since I am deploying many poms at same time, its hard to see where it fails, the error of mvn is this:

```
failed to read artificat descriptor. 
Could not transfer artifact.
uknowon host
```

and the structure of the poms are like this:

```
<snapshotRepository>
    <id>myid</id>
    <name>Repository Name</name>
    <url>url:8081/repositories</url>
    <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
</snapshotRepository>
```

and my settings.xml

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
             <id>myId</id>
             <name>MirrorName</name>
             <url>http://url.com:8081/repositories</url>
             <mirrorOf>*,!public-snapshots,!public-legacy,!sonar</mirrorOf>
       </mirror>
    </mirrors>
</settings>
```

Comment: Can you please add the pom.xml snippet which is giving you the error ?

Comment: Hi, please check the edit on the post.

Comment: As you gave * in `mirrorOf`, it should work. Hope you're connected to internet when trying to download for the first time. Did you check if you're mirror is actually working by hitting that URL directly in browser ?

Comment: well, at the mvn error it shows could not transfer the artificat from/to (localurl) seems like it is not going to the public url... but i also notice, the remote server is url.com:8081/repositories and the local is looking for url:8081/repositories-legacy , so, is basically other folder in the remote server , should I add this other mirror? repositories-legacy?

Comment: Yup add another mirror definition. Basically when you're specifying a mirror for `domain.com/path1`, you should handle other mirrors like `domain.com/path2` as well.

Comment: but, shouldnt it work with !public-legacy on the mirrorOf part?

Comment: Did you actually check if the `id` from `snapshotRepository` and the one used in `mirrorOf` are exactly same ? I mean is it `public-legacy` in both the places, no typos absolutely

Comment: Ive found the issue!! I dont have the version exactly the same, it is looking for a version 5.8 and i hve only 5.7 and 5.9.. is there any way to skip this repo?

Comment: or, there is a way to know the pom that is actually calling this repo? I have many poms compiling at same time and i dont know which one is the one that is calling to this repo.

Comment: You mean the artifact that it's trying is download is of version 5.8 but you have only 5.7/5.9. Can't you just update your pom ?

Comment: are many poms (about 200) and some call other poms, I am trying to figure out a way to know the exact pom that is caling that repo, any idea?

Comment: If you have the source code for all the POMs then a simple search for that artifact that it's trying to download will give you the file name rt ?

Comment: I do, but the poms have a parent pom related.. and they have others and so on, so, I dont know if there is any way to do it with my IDE (intelliJ)